# How do I add a Gutenberg editor to a custom options page

Tags: block-editor, add-submenu-page

Can I add a Gutenberg editor to a custom options page (admin submenu page)? How?

I'd like to create a editor for a 404-page, but I'd prefer not to use a standard page for it since our clients might change it.

Answer (score -1):

The official wordpress docs now includes a guide on how to setup a custom options page using the block editor (Gutenberg).

https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/data-basics/

EDIT:
The language around the Gutenberg editor is sometimes vague (block-editor, Gutenberg Data).

The first page of the link above shows how to get started building [custom options page](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/data-basics/1-data-basics-setup/).

From there you will want to add the [block-editor package](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-block-editor/)

Comment: where does it say it?

Comment: I've updated the answer with more context.